# Azure Automation account Powershell Error setting context

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to run a simple powershell runbook using Azure automation account. I have a RunasAccount setup which has contributor previlege over the subscription and I am trying to get a list of IP's whitelisted in one of my Sql server.

```
Import-Module Az.Sql
Import-Module Az.Accounts
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}


Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName test-rg -ServerName test-server101
```

While I run this I get the below error.

> Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule : No subscription found in the context. Please ensure that the credentials you provided are authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Connect-AzAccount to login. At line:36 char:1 + Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName test-rg -ServerName te ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule], AzPSApplicationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.FirewallRule.Cmdlet.GetAzureSqlServerFirewallRule

I noticed that the  Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule commandlet has an option to set -DefaultProfile. However I am not sure what is to be given here.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing PowerShell modules.  If you're using the Az module, then you need to use `Connect-AzAccount` rather than `Add-AzureRmAccount`.  If you're using the AzureRm module, then you need to use `Get-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule` rather than `Get-AzSqlServerFirewallRule`.